# How do you use both a string and a StringVar in the same label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to write a section of code which will display a number based on the buttons a user presses, and changes a label to display their current number.

I currently have this code, which should provide an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
total = 0
texttotal = StringVar()
texttotal.set(total)
Button(text = "-100", command = lambda: amount_calc(-100)).place(x = 70, y = 512)
Button(text = "-10", command = lambda: amount_calc(-10)).place(x = 108, y = 512)
Button(text = "-1", command = lambda: amount_calc(-1)).place(x = 140, y = 512)
Button(text = "+1", command = lambda: amount_calc(1)).place(x = 166, y = 512)
Button(text = "+10", command = lambda: amount_calc(10)).place(x = 194, y = 512)
Button(text = "+100", command = lambda: amount_calc(100)).place(x = 228, y = 512)

amount_label = Label(text = "Currently adding/removing: ", textvariable = texttotal)
amount_label.place(x = 10, y = 550)
```

and then the "amount_calc" sub program is:

```
def amount_calc(amount):
    total += amount
    texttotal.set(total)
```

How would I go about changing the texttotal variable in the "amount_label" label whilst also keeping the string containing the text within the label?

Comment: texttotal needs to hold the entire string you want to show in the label. In amount_calc `texttotal.set('Currently...' +str(total)) ` is needed.

Comment: Either that or use two labels.

Answer (score 1):

texttotal.get() should get you the desired output in this case. Simply add it to the labels existing string.

Perhaps something like this will work. Note that I put the label as a parameter to the amount_calc function in this case:

```
total = 0
texttotal = StringVar()
texttotal.set(total)
temp = Button(text = "-100", command = lambda: amount_calc(100, amount_label))
...
amount_label = Label(text = "Currently adding/removing: " + texttotal.get())
```

And amount_calc():

```
def amount_calc(amount, amount_label):

    global total
    total += amount
    texttotal.set(total)
    amount_label.config(text="Currently adding/removing: " + texttotal.get())
```

Edit: Added text for clarity and corrected mistakes.

Comment: I have tried this, however I get an error that the variable "total" has been referenced before assignment, however it has been assigned with "total = 0". I'm unsure of why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Did you make a reference to it as a global variable (see my answer, line 3)? In your original post you don't have a local variable named total, and so the reference you're trying to make to total is out of scope.

Comment: I managed to solve it, I got it working by putting setting it as a global variable both before "total = 0" and at the start of the sub program. Unsure as to why I needed to do it twice, but I'm happy I managed to get it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> Question: use both a string and a StringVar in the same label?

Define your own `Label`, you don't need `StringVar`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class TotalLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, pre_text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pre_text = pre_text
        self.set(0)

    def set(self, value):
        self.configure(text='{} {}'.format(self.pre_text, value))


class App(tk.Tk) :
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        total_label = TotalLabel(self, pre_text='Currently adding/removing:')
        total_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        total = 10
        total_label.set(total)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***